# Illustrator: Subtracting lines from a circle with pathfinder

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

Im trying to cut out the leftovers of this circle using pathfinder-intersect, but it's not letting me. Worked before with the same shape, am I missing something?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That only works with **shapes**. Combine your lines to a shape or expand (Object > Expand...) the line thickness to a shape, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

...or use the Shape Builder Tool to trim off the excess lines